# INSERT multiple columns

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I currently need to insert a single line in a database but I have A LOT of columns, a total of 11 (without the ID). I'm using the following command:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11) VALUES (@par1,  @par2,  @par3,  @par4,  @par5,  @par6,  @par7,  @par8,  @par9,  @par10,  @par11)
```

but as you can see it's just too long, I can't avoid using the column names because I still have the ID. Is there a more efficient way to insert? Or maybe a way to make it shorter? Because the way I'm doing I also have to add the parameters one by one like this:

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add(value1, "@par1");
```

Comment: "but as you can see it's just too big" - what do you mean by that? Too big in what sense? It's really unclear what you're asking here.

Comment: @JonSkeet I meant it's long, it's inefficient if I have a database with 25 columns for example, it takes a long time just to write a single line and add the parameters.

Comment: Are you really worrying about the efficiency of typing the code, or execution-time efficiency? Sure, if you have lots of values, that's going to end up as more code, but I don't really see the problem here.

Comment: @JonSkeet Well, I'm assuming that I have a limited time to make the basic operations in a database using ADO.NET but the database has 3 tables and each table a lot of columns. It happened to me a few weeks ago and I'm trying to solve this problem.

Comment: In the time you've spent asking this question, you could already have written the code for the insert statements. Seriously, I would be *absolutely astonished* if this aspect formed a significant proportion of the time taken to write your overall app.

Comment: (If you were to use an ORM you may be able to avoid writing the SQL statement itself, but I wouldn't base the decision of whether or not to use an ORM on "I don't want to write a long insert statement and a line of code per column.")

Comment: I'm not asking to be lazy or anything (if this is what you meant), I've always done this way and I ran out of time by doing this. I just want to know if there's a more efficient way, just that.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by run out of time?  Do you mean you missed your work deadline because you couldn't finish writing your program fast enough?  IF so you're probably dealing with unrealistic deadlines.  If you mean something else, then you'll need to enlighten us.

Comment: @Sentinel I had a test in a job interview and one part of the test was to make these basic operations using a database they provided and it had tons of columns, the columns had foreign keys and I had to check all possible errors like null values, empty textboxes, etc..., I've been searching for a shorter statement or a different way to add the parameters, I could have saved a lot of time if I knew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Thank you again @Sentinel for reminding me to keep an eye on potential security risks. This kind of approach is language indepenedent, but I do agree with his suggestion that you could also still use `myCommand.Parameters.Add(values[N], "@parN");` instead of building a string for the values as well.

Expanding on @Javies Insuasti answer.

This answer assumes that you're using a string to build your SQL query.

This is a common and easy to handle scenario. The easiest way to handle this (imho) is to use markers in your string, create arrays/lists of your columns and values, and replace the markers with the content of those arrays/lists.

```
using System;

class Program
{

    //defining a blacklist of unwanted terms that should not appear in your column names or value strings
    //This is just for the sake of the example, and there are definitely some statements missing in this array
    static string[] QUERY_BLACKLIST = { "SELECT", "DROP", "INSERT", "DELETE", "UPDATE" };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    //Use markers in your query string
    string query = "INSERT INTO table (:columns:) VALUES (:values:);";
    //define an array of column names to insert for the :columns: marker
    string[] columns = { "ID", "Name", "Age", "Something"};
    //some dummy values. Real code would use a model or something to that effect
    int id = 9;
    string name = "John";
    int age = 12;
    bool something = true;
    //all values should be passed as strings, they will replace the :values: marker
    string[] values = { id.ToString(), name, age.ToString(), something.ToString()};
    query = Program.FillColumnsIntoQuery(query, columns, values);
    Console.WriteLine(query);
    //Output:
    //"INSERT INTO table (ID,Name,Age,Something) VALUES ('9','John','12','true');"

    //example for the blacklist check
    query = "INSERT INTO table (:columns:) VALUES (:values:);";
    //strings with malicious intent behind them
    string[] columns2 =  { "DROP table" };
    string[] values2 = { "DELETE * FROM table" };
    try
    {
        query = Program.FillColumnsIntoQuery(query, columns2, values2);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        //Output:
        //"Someone is trying to do evil stuff!"
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static string FillColumnsAndValuesIntoInsertQuery(string query, string[] colums, string[] values)
    {
    //joining the string arrays with a comma character
    string columnnames = string.Join(",", colums);
    //adding values with single quotation marks around them to handle errors related to string values
    string valuenames = "'" + string.Join("','", values) + "'"; ; 

    //we need to check every entry of the blacklist against the provided strings
    foreach(string blacklist in QUERY_BLACKLIST)
    {
        if(columnnames.ToLower().IndexOf(blacklist.ToLower()) >= 0
        || valuenames.ToLower().IndexOf(blacklist.ToLower()) >=0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Someone is trying to do evil stuff!");
        }
    }

    //replacing the markers with the desired column names and values
    return query.Replace(":columns:",columnnames).Replace(":values:", valuenames);
    }
}
```

If you want to be fancy, you could write an extension method for the string class. You could pass the markers as well. You could write functions that build query templates for you. You could choose a shorter name for the function.

The possibilities are endless :-).

Comment: You need to be careful with dynamic SQL.  A malicious user could provide inputs that corrupt your dynamically built query to have unintended results.  For that reason it's better to keep the query parameterized, but you can still loop through the array for the values, build the list of parameters names and use `myCommand.Parameters.Add(values[N], "@parN");` to map the names to parameters.

Comment: @Sentinel Good point, totally slipped my mind. In order to be safe, you could try to make absolutely sure that the column names and value string do not contain any kind of SQL statements. Which in effect would mean an additional array, looping through columns and values before joining them and performing an indexOf check against the blacklist of unwanted terms. This is quite important and I thank you for reminding me of it.

Answer (score 0):

That's really not that much different than populating the members of any data structure in any other language.  If you're not populating every member of the data structure you have to specify each member that you are populating, weather you specify it in a set based manner as with SQL or as separate attribute value pairs as in `set object.attribute = value`.

However, as with any other language you may be able to write a function or procedure to hide some of those details, such that you only need to pass in the appropriate variables.  Then you only need to write out all of the detailed code once for any given scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Put all values into a List, and use For Loop, and insert one by one a List value in

Comment: I think you should replace "values" with "column names" for clarity. Otherwise this is the way I would go.